# How to check if OS is 32bit or 64bit in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a library which is only available for 32bit architecture. How can i check OS CPU architecture via code in react native?

Answer (score 1):

Use `react-native-device-info` for this.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#supported32bitabis

`supported32BitAbis()
 An ordered list of 32 bit ABIs supported by this device.`

Example.

```
DeviceInfo.supported64BitAbis().then(abis => {
  // ["arm64-v8a"]
});
```

`supported64BitAbis()
An ordered list of 64 bit ABIs supported by this device.`

Example.

```
DeviceInfo.supported64BitAbis().then(abis => {
 // ["arm64-v8a"]
});
```

Comment: I think it just give the list of CPU architectures added in gradle file of project. Actually i want to know that current running device is 32 bit or 64bit? is it possible with this?

Comment: have a look at this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/issues/578